# OnScreenResize Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такой код

```
bounds = new Rect(upLeft.transform.position.x, downRight.transform.position.y,
downRight.transform.position.x - upLeft.transform.position.x,
upLeft.transform.position.y - downRight.transform.position.y);
```

Он рисует прямоугольник в зависимости от размера экрана. 
Вопрос - как постоянно отслеживать события изменения разрешения экрана? 
Есть ли в Unity какой нибудь метод типа OnScreenResize?
Или единственный вариант - ставить в Update? В таком случае, не слишком ли будет его нагружать создание нового квадрата каждый кадр?

Comment: Есть `Screen.width` и `Screen.height`. Можно создать метод или событие, при котором будут отслеживаться эти параметры, если они изменились - значит нужно делать то, что нужно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Про метод понятно - ставим в Update и проверяем каждый кадр. А что насчёт события? Это менее затратно? Можно подробнее?

Comment: События - это нужно почитать немного основ C#. http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level10/10_7.php  https://habrahabr.ru/post/213809/  и пр. Суть в том, что создается эвент (событие), которое уведомляет всех подписчиков при определенном условии. Например, при смене размера вам нужно 1) написать что-то в лог (один метод) 2) убрать всех мобов (еще один метод) 3) пересчитать что-то (третий метод).  Так вот, вы создаете событие, подписываете на него эти методы, а когда срабатывает изменение экрана, то это событие как бы триггерит (запускает) все эти методы.

Comment: По факту, даже методы Update и корутины можно построить на системе эвентов, сложно, но можно. Ведь вся игра это по сути реагирование чего-то на какое-либо событие.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Благодарю за подробный ответ, но я знаю что такое события. Я подразумеваю, как мне отследить изменение размера экрана? Ведь для срабатывания события нужно чтобы кто то проверял размер экрана, постоянно. Опять Update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно создавать прямоугольник в каждом кадре, его можно объявить в классе, инициализировать в Start(), а в Update() только обновлять значения. И это не будет затратно, поскольку собственно операция присвоения будет происходить только при смене значений. Плюс это просто четыре числа, так что, в общем-то, оно и так бы не было особо затратно.

**UPDATE**

Примерно так:

```
public Rect bounds;

void Start()
{
    bounds = new Rect(upLeft.transform.position.x,   downRight.transform.position.y,
    downRight.transform.position.x - upLeft.transform.position.x,
    upLeft.transform.position.y - downRight.transform.position.y);
}

void Update()
{
    bounds.width = newWidth; //ваша формула пересчёта
    //x, y, height - аналогично
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Вообще говоря, Update() и FixedUpdate() - главные игровые циклы (они имеют приблизительно одинаковый смысл, но есть один нюанс). Не нужно бояться помещать туда разнообразный код, они для этого и нужны. Конечно, необходимо следить за производительностью, для чего есть [профайлер](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/520/Manual/Profiler.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Подскажите, как именно это сделать? Я знаю как создавать прямоугольник, но как менять его значения? Это же не вектор.

Comment: @Dmitrii Добавил в ответ пример

Answer (score 2):

В самом компоненте Canvas поменять Render Mode на "Screen Space - Camera".  В поле "Render Camera" за аттачить камеру, отвечающий за UI (обычно это Main Camera). вставить элемент кода в скрпит

```
CanvasScaler scaler = gameObject.GetComponent<CanvasScaler>();
Vector2 resolution = scaler.referenceResolution;
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation;
```

повесить скрипт на Canvas. Вытащить через Singleton размер канваса.

Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html